# Get variable from Ansible docker_image_info

Tags: ansible

I have this information with this playbook:

---

- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

  ```
  - name: Get infos on container
    docker_image_info:
      name: 'docker555.nibus.tda/ti-aes/testajr:16048'
    register: result
  ```

The result is:

ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "images": [
            {
                "Architecture": "amd64",
                "Author": "",
                "Comment": "",
                "Config": {
                    "ArgsEscaped": true,
                    "AttachStderr": false,
                    "AttachStdin": false,
                    "AttachStdout": false,
                    "Cmd": [
                        "/bin/sh",
                        "-c",
                        "touch /tmp/aes_new.txt"
                    ],
                    "Domainname": "",
                    "Entrypoint": null,
                    "Env": [
                        "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                        "container=oci"
                    ],
                    "Hostname": "427d6aa4c22a",
                    "Image": "sha256:ccd7c25ced1247cc652e2bd637281ce5fcfb1df9e0296d6acce247cf25d2b5b2",
                    "Labels": {
                        "architecture": "x86_64",
                        "authoritative-source-url": "registry.access.redhat.com",
                        "build-date": "2020-01-29T19:42:00.195495",
                        "com.redhat.build-host": "cpt-1001.osbs.prod.upshift.rdu2.redhat.com",
                        "com.redhat.component": "ubi8-minimal-container",
                        "com.redhat.license_terms": "https://www.redhat.com/en/about/red-hat-end-user-license-agreements#UBI",
                        "description": "The Universal Base Image Minimal is a stripped down image that uses microdnf as a package manager. This base image is freely redistributable, but Red Hat only supports Red Hat technologies through subscriptions for Red Hat products. This image is maintained by Red Hat and updated regularly.",
                        "distribution-scope": "public",
                        "io.k8s.description": "The Universal Base Image Minimal is a stripped down image that uses microdnf as a package manager. This base image is freely redistributable, but Red Hat only supports Red Hat technologies through subscriptions for Red Hat products. This image is maintained by Red Hat and updated regularly.",
                        "io.k8s.display-name": "Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 Minimal",
                        "io.openshift.expose-services": "",
                        "io.openshift.tags": "minimal rhel8",
                        "maintainer": "Red Hat, Inc.",
                        "name": "ubi8-minimal",
                        "release": "398",
                        "summary": "Provides the latest release of the minimal Red Hat Universal Base Image 8.",

```
                    "vcs-ref": "8c3c7acc321ed054dded6e6e13b5c09c043f42dc",
                    "vcs-type": "git",
                    "vendor": "Red Hat, Inc.",
                    "version": "8.1"
                },
```

Is possible get only this info for one variable:

"release": "398",

Thanks

Comment: Please fix question formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) module.

```
- name: set_fact from result
  set_fact:
    release: "{{ result.images[0].Config.Labels.release }}"
```